# RoyalSlider Plugin Thumbnails issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to understand what is broken in the thumbnail (they are not centered and start scrolling from the left) in this website [Link to](http://www.alexanderhotels.co.uk/rowhill-grange-luxury-hotel-kent/gallery.html)

The site uses Royalslider jquery plugin
anyone has an idea?

Comment: Which browser? Seems OK on Chrome.

Comment: All browsers I think.  Chrome,Safari,Mozilla that I can open know are showing the same behavior

Comment: Right, Currently the thumbnails below the slider are correctly, 'following' the slider above it - thus scrolling to the left when you reach past the 8th slide, right? I suppose you'd prefer it to stay in the middle and not follow the slider, and instead act as a viewport for the slider above?

Comment: Yes I prefer if they start in the middle...always centered...I think is the default behavior of this plugin..but there is a lot of custom js involved..if you look at the source code...

Comment: I don't think there's a quick 'option' for what you're asking, so yes - you'd have to script it, because currently there's alot of `margin` or `left`/`right` pushing on event new slide on the current page you've linked.

Comment: Thanks for your time...I will think about a solution